# Looking for an optimisation algorithm

Tags: matrices, optimization, coloring

I have an optimisation problem and I'm looking for the best algorithm to solve it.

I have a sparse matrix (only 0 and 1, R and C stay for rows and columns) such as:

```
   | C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 | C5 | C6 |
----------------------------------
R1 |  1 |  0 |  0 |  1 |  0 |  0 |
R2 |  0 |  1 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |
R3 |  0 |  1 |  1 |  0 |  1 |  1 |
R4 |  0 |  0 |  1 |  0 |  0 |  0 |
R5 |  1 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |
```

I need to merge the rows so that the "1" appears only in at most one of the merged rows (for example, R2 and R3 cannot be merged because both rows have a "1" in column C2), and so to minimise the total number of zero in the whole matrix.
The final goal is to find (and merge) the rows that do not share any "1" on the same column.

Using the above example, I can do it in several ways.

Solution 1.

```
      | C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 | C5 | C6 |
-------------------------------------
R1+R2 |  1 |  1 |  0 |  1 |  0 |  0 |
R3    |  0 |  1 |  1 |  0 |  1 |  1 |
R4+R5 |  1 |  0 |  1 |  0 |  0 |  0 |
```

Solution 2.

```
         | C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 | C5 | C6 |
-------------------------------------
R1+R4+R2 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  0 |  0 |
R3+R5    |  1 |  1 |  1 |  0 |  1 |  1 |
```

Solution 3.

```
            | C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 | C5 | C6 |
-------------------------------------------
R1+R3       |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |
R2+R4+R5    |  1 |  1 |  1 |  0 |  0 |  0 |
```

All the presented solutions cannot be reduced any more, but the second and the third options are clearly more efficient w.r.t. the first one.

In my problem, I need to deal with a matrix MxN where M and N are more than some hundreds.

Is there an algorithm that can find the optimal solution?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have edited the text, hoping that now it's clearer.

Comment: Thanks, now it's clear : you can sum two rows if there is no "2" in their sum.

Comment: Do you know "Dynamic programming" ? I am almost sure that there is an algorithm of this family for your problem.

Comment: I've heard about dynamic programming, but I've never tried it. I'll have a look, thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Solution #2 should be $(R1+R2+R4)\;(R3+R5)$ which is equally optimal to Solution #3.

Comment: Thank @greg, now the text is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is equivalent to the minimum vertex coloring problem:

- your matrix is representing a graph
- each row corresponds to a vertex
- two rows both having a 1 in the same column are connected by an edge
- merging rows is equivalent to giving them the same color
- vertexes that are connected by an edge must have different colors
- you want the minimum amount of colors to be used

Unfortunately this is a NP-complete problem, but there exist approximation algorithms like [DSatur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DSatur) and the [Recursive largest first algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_largest_first_algorithm)

Comment: To show that the matrix problem is as hard as vertex coloring, you might want to clarify that there is a reduction *from* vertex coloring *to* the matrix problem (by creating a row for each vertex and a column for each edge of the given graph).

Comment: Right, there are two reductions needed here.

The one I showed is from the matrix problem to vertex coloring, and the idea behind it is that there are likely many algorithms to solve vertex coloring, so you can just use them.

It shows one way to solve the problem, but doesn't show that you can't do better than that. Thus, as you said, a second reduction from vertex coloring to the matrix problem is also needed to show that the matrix problem is also NP-complete. It should be pretty easy to find it once you get the intuition from the first reduction though.

Answer (score 0):

Using dynamic programming try this:
State variable: Count of $0$: $ x_0 = \vert [0] \vert$
Stage (rows): $t=5$
Optimal function: Joining rows
Optimal function: $ f_t = f_{t-1}+t$
Boundary function (basically first optimal):
$$ f_1 = \min_{x_0}[R_1 +\{R_i: R_1+R_i \le 1 \ \ \forall i \in R\}]$$
Set of rows merged optimally
$$f_2 = \min_{x_0} [R_3 + f_1,R4+f_1] $$
$ .$
$.$
$.$
$$ f_t = min[R_t + f_{t-1}: R_t+f_{t-1} \le 1 \quad t \in R \setminus f$$
$ $